# How to convert Spark dense vector to separate colunms with their index in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, vector, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert spark dense vectors to separate columns with their index in Scala? Hope some help, please~

I have a dataframe after minMaxScaler :

```
+---+--------+--------------------+---------------------+
| id|category|minMaxScalerFeatures|scaledFeatures_output|
+---+--------+--------------------+---------------------+
|  0|      66|          [0.0,66.0]|            [0.0,0.0]|
|  1|      98|          [1.0,98.0]|            [0.5,1.0]|
|  2|      90|          [2.0,90.0]|           [1.0,0.75]|
+---+--------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

I want to get the value after scaler with their index, like the pattern "index:value" which is String type:

```
+---+--------+--------------------+-----------------------+
| id|category|minMaxScalerFeatures|scaledFeatures_output  |
+---+--------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|  0|      66|          [0.0,66.0]|            0:0.0,1:0.0|
|  1|      98|          [1.0,98.0]|            0:0.5,1:1.0|
|  2|      90|          [2.0,90.0]|           0:1.0,1:0.75|
+---+--------+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

Code to generate the data:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df_1 = Seq((0, 66),(1, 98),(2, 90)).toDF("id", "category")

val minMax_columns = Array("id", "category")

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(minMax_columns)
  .setOutputCol("minMaxScalerFeatures")

val scaler = new MinMaxScaler()
  .setInputCol("minMaxScalerFeatures")
  .setOutputCol("scaledFeatures_output")

val dataset = assembler.transform(df_1)

val scalerModel = scaler.fit(dataset)

val scaledData = scalerModel.transform(dataset)
```

Thank U very much~ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how will you complete this task on an array. I would personnaly do that (which may not be optimal but it works) :

```
var s = ""
for(i <- 0 until array.length) s = s + s"$i:${a(i)}"
s = s.dropRight(1)
```

Now you can include that in an user defined function and it's done:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val myudf = udf((arr: DenseVector) => {
    val a = arr.toArray
    var s = ""
    for(i <- 0 until a.length) s = s + s"$i:${a(i)},"
    s.dropRight(1)
})
```

Comment: Thank U very much~ :) I have tried zipWithIndex, but failed~